# How to use array of XPath in robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, xpath-2.0

I have html table which has some one column and N rows. I want to traverse through the array. Since HTML table does not have unique locator. I am using `@class` attribute to get the rows This is my xpath which gives me matching rows.

`//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')]`.

When i add index to it like this:

`(//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')])[3]`,

it works fine in firebox/seleniumIDE.

However with RobotFramework, it works only for first row.

Works:

```
//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')][1]
```

Does not work:

```
//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')][2]
//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')][3]
//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')][4]
```

BTW, enclosing entire element in round bracket does not work.

```
(//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')])[4]
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Can you post the DOM structure here? The table along with 3-4 tr's and td's would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Here is the answer. Simply use "xpath=" as prefix to your xpath. Here is the example

```
xpath=(//td[contains(@class,'td-entity-field-super-parent')])[4]
```